# React TypeScript Object becomes undefined if it accesses state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-redux

I have a plain old color class that I've been using in many places in my app:

```
const Color = {
    [...]
    cardBackground: '#f8f8f8',
    sidebarBackground: '#eeeeee',
    viewportBackground: '#D8D8D8',
    [...]
}

export default Color;
```

It simply works. Now I want to implement dark mode support without changing external modifications to the code. I decided to hook up to state, read it directly and return the appropriate value in getter:

```
const Color = {
    [...]
    cardBackground: '#f8f8f8',
    get sidebarBackground(){ return lightDark('#eeeeee','#222222') },
    viewportBackground: '#D8D8D8',
    [...]
}

export default Color;
```

Where `lightDark` is defined as:

```
export function lightDark<T1, T2>(light:T1, dark:T2){
    return themeSelector(store.getState()) == 'dark' ? dark : light;
}
```

Now I suddenly get an `undefined` error in the first place where `Color` is accessed (not necessarily `Color.sidebarBackground`, but anything inside `Color`)

If I modify the code to remove access to the state (just for testing), it starts working:

```
export function lightDark<T1, T2>(light:T1, dark:T2){
  return themeSelector({session:{theme:'dark'}} as any)  == 'dark' ? dark : light;
}
```

What on Earth is going on?

For clarificaition, this is the exact error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

where I try to access `Color.title`, which appears to be the first reference to `Color` in my app (thus, `title` is irrelevant).

I also realized that the moment I reference `store` *in any way at all* in the file where `Color` is defined, `Color` becomes undefined. Even `console.log(store);` causes `Color` to become undefined.

Comment: What exactly is it that's undefined with the store version? Do you mean that `Color.sidebarBackground` results in `Cannot read sidebarBackground of undefined`?

Comment: Any chance that the `themeSelector` method can't handle the return value of `store.getState()` and it crashes? Does `console.log('state: ', store.getState())` give additional clues?

Comment: @Andreas_D the moment I reference `store` in any way, `Color` becomes `undefined`, I've updated the question.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes too. And your problem is truely weird. 'store' is the redux store?

Comment: - Asking, because I don't understand how assigning an object would invalidate other variables. Unless you have a `get` method on a class that returns the store and executes some additional code - which may fail.

Comment: @Andreas_D yup, it's the redux store. accessing it in the same file, even if it's completely unrelated to the object, causes that object (which is a POJSO) to become undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: something `import`ed in `store` was *indirectly* accessing `Color` at some point, creating a hard-to-detect circular dependency. I got rid of the reference by refactoring a little bit and the problem is solved.